# How to find the path to load a file in a nested directory?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, hmvc

I would load the view `welcome_message.php` in `main.php` in a nested directory but i didn't success to do it.

Codeigniter application directory:

```
/*
+ controllers
|-+ main.php
|-+ modules
  |-+ publicview
  | |-+ welcome
  |   |-+ controllers
  |     |-+ Welcome.php
  |     |-+ models
  |     |-+ views
  |       |-+ welcome_message.php // <- How to load this ?
  |-+ views
    |-+ templateview
*/
```

`main.php` codes:

```
public function index($uri=1)
{
    $this->template->load('publictemplate','publicview/welcome/welcome_message');
}
```

Comment: This is not the Proper HMVC Codeigniter.  Its wrong

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
public function index($uri=1)
{
    $this->template->load('publictemplate','publicview/welcome/controllers/views/welcome_message');
}
```